# Expectation of a function of a Gumbel distributed random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Given that the moment generating function for standard Gumbel distributed $X$ is

1. $m(t) = \Gamma(1-t)$,
2. $\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$,
3. the log-derivative $\psi(z)= d\log(\Gamma(z))/dz = \Gamma'(z)/\Gamma(z)$,
4. $\psi(1)=-\gamma =$Euler-Mascheroni constant and
5. $\psi'(1) = \pi^2/6$,

compute $E(e^{-X})$, $E(Xe^{-X})$ and $E(X^2e^{-X})$.

For the first one I have:
$$E(e^{-X})=\Gamma(1-(-1))=1$$
But for the second and third one I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: The moment generating function is given by $m(t) =E [e^{tX}]$. Assuming that you can exchange integration and differentiation, what do you get by differentiating $m(t)$?

Comment: @Mick I would get the moments, and I know that I am supposed to somehow differentiate the $m(t)$, however I don't know how to apply $E(X) = m(t)'_{t=0}$ to $E(Xe^-{X})$.

Comment: e.g. $E[Xe^{tX}] = m'(t) $, hence $ E[Xe^{-X}] = m'(-1)
 $